# How do you produce a 3-dimensional pivot table in plsql

Tags: plsql, pivot-table

I have a need to produce the following table (National Institute of Health format):

[image]

I have no problem dealing with the layout but generating the 3-dimensional pl/sql data table is another thing.

How do you do the last query?

I already have the pivot coding for the race v ethnic data:

```
total_demographics as
(
    SELECT 
        ETHNICITY, 
        RACE,
        race_number
    FROM study_demographics
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        'Total' as ETHNICITY, 
        RACE,
        ethnicity_number
    FROM study_demographics
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        ETHNICITY,
        'Total' as RACE, 
        race_number
    FROM study_demographics
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        'Total' as ETHNICITY,
        'Total' as RACE, 
        row_number
    FROM study_demographics
 )
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ETHNICITY,
            RACE
        FROM
            total_demographics
    )
PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(RACE)
        FOR (RACE) IN (
            'Not Reported',
            'Other',
            'American Indian', 
            'Asian',
            'Black',
            'Declined',
            'More than one race',
            'Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander',
            'Unknown',
            'White',
            'Total'
            )
    )
ORDER BY (
    case ETHNICITY
        when 'Missing' then 0
        when 'Declined' then 1
        when 'Hispanic or Latino' then 2
        when 'Non-Hispanic' then 3
        when 'Unknown' then 4
        when 'Total' then 5
        else
            6
    end
            )
```

I have never done a 3-dimensional table although I can generate the gender-related information and add it to the pl/sql as well.

**UPDATE - SOLUTION FOUND**

I located the following stackoverflow post which helped me develop the solution I was looking for:   [Using pivot on multiple columns of an Oracle row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939244/using-pivot-on-multiple-columns-of-an-oracle-row).

I was able to get the result I wanted with the following sql block:

```
study_demographics AS
(
  SELECT  study_number, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ETHNICITY, RACE, GENDER ORDER BY ETHNICITY, RACE, GENDER) AS line_number,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ETHNICITY ORDER BY RACE ASC) AS ethnicity_number,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RACE ORDER BY ETHNICITY, GENDER ASC) AS race_number,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GENDER ORDER BY ETHNICITY, GENDER ASC) AS gender_number,
    ETHNICITY,
    RACE,
    GENDER
 FROM
    total_study_demographics
 ),
 total_demographics as
 (
 SELECT DISTINCT
    ETHNICITY, 
    GENDER,
    RACE,
    line_number
FROM study_demographics
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    'Total' as ETHNICITY, 
    GENDER as GENDER,
    RACE as RACE, 
    race_number
FROM study_demographics
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    ETHNICITY as ETHNICITY,
    GENDER as GENDER,
    'Total' as RACE, 
    gender_number
FROM study_demographics
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    ETHNICITY as ETHNICITY,
    'Total' as GENDER, 
    RACE,
    race_number
FROM study_demographics
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Total' as ETHNICITY,
    'Total' as GENDER,
    'Total' as RACE, 
    line_number
FROM study_demographics
)
SELECT 
 *
FROM
(
SELECT
        RACE, MNH_G, FNH_G, UNH_G, MH_G, FH_G, UH_G, MU_G, FU_G, UU_G, (TNH_G + THL_G + TU_G + TOTAL_G) AS TOTAL
 FROM
 (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        total_demographics

 PIVOT
 (
    COUNT(line_number) as G
    FOR (GENDER, ETHNICITY) IN (
        ('Male','Non-Hispanic') AS MNH,
        ('Female','Non-Hispanic') AS FNH,
        ('Unknown','Non-Hispanic') AS UNH,
        ('Male','Hispanic or Latino') AS MH,
        ('Female','Hispanic or Latino') AS FH,
        ('Unknown','Hispanic or Latino') AS UH,
        ('Male','Unknown') AS MU,
        ('Female','Unknown') AS FU,
        ('Unknown','Unknown') AS UU,
        ('Total','Non-Hispanic') AS TNH,
        ('Total','Hispanic or Latino') AS THL,
        ('Total','Unknown') AS TU,
        ('Total','Total') AS Total
        )       
)
ORDER BY (
case RACE
    when 'American Indian' then 0
    when 'Asian' then 1
    when 'Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander' then 2
    when 'Black' then 3
    when 'White' then 4
    when 'More than one race' then 5
    when 'Unknown' then 6
    when 'Total' then 7
    else
        8
 END
        )
        )
 )
```

The key to the solution was the FOR clause in the pivot table and propagating the combinations of results and totals.

The resulting table looks like this in sqldeveloper:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a small sample of data from your study_demographics table. Also, please explain any special groupings of race/ethnicity/gender. For example, do all of the "Missing", "Declined", and "Unknown" values for ethnicity get counted under the "Unknown/Not Reported Ethnicity" columns?

Comment: I determined the solution today and am updating the question.

Comment: The input query, study_demographics, involves the use of a proprietary package and is not really critical to the answer.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I was going to suggest using CUBE - [Using ROLL UP/CUBE in conjunction with PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743769/20324967) and the PIVOT with multiple columns that you found.

Comment: I use partitioning rather than grouping so cube and rollup are not needed and I use the counter columns to get the totals for both horizontal and vertical.  My approach might take longer to run, but I have more control of the output,